# how to open Bottomsheet from the bottom of the BottomNavigation bar in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet, android-jetpack-navigation

How to open Bottomsheet from the bottom of the BottomNavigation bar in compose? I am using currently BottomSheetScaffold, it's part of the one tab and it opened above on BottomNaviagtion Tab. But my requirement is open from the bottom.
I know there is already bottomSheet() type to define in navigation, but its own has bugs and hasn't a full feature of expand-collapse function.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue?